# jQuery count the number of dynamic add element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

Refer to attached screenshot, the div with id 'item' were added by

```
$("#items").prepend(template);
```

where template is the html of each div with id 'item', if I get $('#item').length but it always return 1, does anyone know why? How can I get the correct number of item?

```
var num = $('#item').length;
alert(num);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `class` attribute instead of `id` attribute since `id` attribute should be unique within the page. A sample of it would look like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addItem").click(function() {
    var template = '<div class="item">Item</div>';
    $("#items").prepend(template);
    var num = $(".item").length; // <--- notice here
    alert(num);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="items"></div>
<button id="addItem">Add Item</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: and where in your example are you using classes?

Answer (score 0):

You are appending a new element with `id = "item"` to another element with `id = "items"`, so what you actually need is the number of children inside `#items`:

```
$("#items").children().length;
```

In any case, as @mandy8055 has pointed out, you are creating multiple items with duplicate ids (`#item`). You can easily fix that using a class instead, so the following would work:

```
$(".item").length
```